# Why i'm getting exception in listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

First i'm getting list of all my youtube videos.
In videosList and videosUrl there are 89 items.
Then when it's getting to the line:

```
this.listBox1.SelectedIndex = 80;
```

It's jumping to the event: listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged and when it's doing the line inside:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = videosUrl[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
```

I'm getting the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation.

Not sure why it happen.

Even if i tried now to change this line to index 0: `this.listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;` I'm getting the same exception.

```
static List<string> videosList = new List<string>();
        static List<string> videosUrl = new List<string>();
        public async void RetrieveUploadsList()
        {
            UserCredentials();
            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            });

            var channelsListRequest = youtubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails");
            channelsListRequest.Mine = true;

            var channelsListResponse = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

            foreach (var channel in channelsListResponse.Items)
            {
                // From the API response, extract the playlist ID that identifies the list
                // of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
                var uploadsListId = channel.ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads;

                Console.WriteLine("Videos in list {0}", uploadsListId);

                var nextPageToken = "";
                while (nextPageToken != null)
                {
                    var playlistItemsListRequest = youtubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
                    playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId = uploadsListId;
                    playlistItemsListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
                    playlistItemsListRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;

                    // Retrieve the list of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
                    var playlistItemsListResponse = await playlistItemsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

                    foreach (var playlistItem in playlistItemsListResponse.Items)
                    {
                            videosList.Add(playlistItem.Snippet.Title + "  " + playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId);
                            videosUrl.Add("http://www.youtube.com/v/" + playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId);
                            listBox1.Items.Add(playlistItem.Snippet.Title + "  " + playlistItem.Snippet.PublishedAt);                  
                    }
                    nextPageToken = playlistItemsListResponse.NextPageToken;
                }
            }
            if (this.listBox1.Items.Count > 80)
            {
                this.listBox1.SelectedIndex = 80;
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = videosUrl[80];
            }
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = videosUrl[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
        }
```

UPDATE

I used now try and catch over the line that make the exception.
What i see is first:

base = {"Exception of type 'System.Windows.Forms.AxHost+InvalidActiveXStateException' was thrown."}

Then stacktrace:

at AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer.set_URL(String value)
   at Automatic_Record.Youtuber.listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\Automatic_Record\Automatic_Record\Automatic_Record\Youtuber.cs:line 393

line 393 is:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = videosUrl[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
```

videosUrl contain 89 items.
On index 0 i see in the videosUrl: http://www.youtube.com/v/gJSXvCiCMCw
And listBox1.SelectedIndex is 0

I also checked now in my youtube the first video is fine i can play it without a problem.

Comment: You'll have to look at the InnerException to know what went wrong.  My crystal ball says that you need to move the call to the method to the Load event.

Comment: In the innerException i see null and inside: _COMPlusExceptionCode = -532462766

Comment: Are you using background threads at all?

Comment: Moved to the form1 load event same exception. In fact it's a new form that i'm making instance of it in form1 constructor and then only make Show() to this form. But that's not should be a problem.

Comment: Chris i have one backgroundworker but i check now to make sure i start it only once after making openFileDialog in a button click so the backgroundworker not started yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that the object returned from `videosUrl[listBox1.SelectedIndex]` is not a string. When you try to assign it to the URL property, it's complaining.

Try debugging this code instead;

```
var selectedItem = videosUrl[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
var selectedItemType = selectedItem.GetType().FullName;
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = selectedItem;
```

My guess is that selectedItemType needs to be `System.String` but will be something like `System.Windows.Forms.ListBoxItem`, and you'll probably need to extract off the name of the item like

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = videosUrl[listBox1.SelectedIndex].Text;
```

Comment: This is working. I also did a mess with two windows media player controls. Thanks everyone now it's working fine.